# Unity IAP (2.2.7 & 3.0.1) consumable item, transaction completion issue

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I have 12 consumable items in "Ready To Submit" status and I am trying to purchase 1 of them again and again by using
a sandbox tester account. In the initialization process, I can receive the product successfully. I can initiate a purchase flow by giving the name
of the product. In the "ProcessPurchase" callback, I can read all required data like transactionId, payload, etc. and completing the process
by returning PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete. I expect UnityIAP to complete the transaction and make the current item available to purchase again.

The problem is, when I try to buy the previous item again, it shows "This In-App Purchase has already been bought" popup. Here is the log file :

```
PurchaseController - ,Purchasing product asychronously: 'mini_coin_pack'
PurchaseController:BuyProductID(String)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

2021-04-15 15:34:14.006798+0300 mygame[1689:850412] UnityIAP: PurchaseProduct: mini_coin_pack
purchase(mini_coin_pack)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

2021-04-15 15:34:14.048335+0300 mygame[1689:850412] UnityIAP: UpdatedTransactions
-> applicationWillResignActive()
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
2021-04-15 15:34:22.947604+0300 mygame[1689:850412] UnityIAP: UpdatedTransactions
2021-04-15 15:34:22.948039+0300 mygame[1689:850412] UnityIAP: DuplicateTransaction error with product mini_coin_pack and transactionId 1000000801477725
-> applicationWillResignActive()
onPurchaseFailedEvent(productId:mini_coin_pack message:Duplicate transaction occurred)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnPurchaseFailed(PurchaseFailureDescription)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

PurchaseController - ,OnPurchaseFailed, Product : mini_coin_pack, Reason : DuplicateTransaction
PurchaseController:OnPurchaseFailed(Product, PurchaseFailureReason)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

PurchaseController - ,Store specific error code: Unknown
PurchaseController:OnPurchaseFailed(Product, PurchaseFailureReason)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

PurchaseController - ,Purchase failure description message: Duplicate transaction occurred
PurchaseController:OnPurchaseFailed(Product, PurchaseFailureReason)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
```

When I kill and relaunch the app, following logs show that there is still a transaction to complete from previous try.

```
2021-04-15 15:35:03.181235+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Created
2021-04-15 15:35:03.182006+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Registered for lifecycle events
CrashReporter: initialized
2021-04-15 15:35:03.215730+0300 mygame[1699:852283] Built from '2019.4/staging' branch, Version '2019.4.23f1 (3f4e01f1a5ec)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
2021-04-15 15:35:03.228051+0300 mygame[1699:852283] MemoryManager: Using 'Default' Allocator.
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2021-04-15 15:35:03.528270+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Added to the payment queue
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A8 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2019.4.23f1 (3f4e01f1a5ec)
CrashReporter: No pending report exists at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/01EA9697-0BD5-40AF-BB20-967567B5EAE2/Library/Caches/CrashReports/crash-pending.plcrash
UnloadTime: 1.242625 ms
UnityIAP Version: 3.0.1
UnityEngine.Purchasing.StandardPurchasingModule:Instance(AppStore)
PurchaseController:InitializePurchasing()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

2021-04-15 15:35:06.133617+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP: Requesting 1 products
2021-04-15 15:35:06.201046+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP: Requesting product data...
2021-04-15 15:35:07.031669+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP: Received 1 products
PurchaseController - ,OnInitialized
PurchaseController:OnInitialized(IStoreController, IExtensionProvider)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

PurchaseController - ,Mini Coin Pack, is ready to purchase!
PurchaseController:OnInitialized(IStoreController, IExtensionProvider)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

UnityIAP: Initialization complete with  1 items
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Promo:ProvideProductsToAds(HashSet`1, Boolean)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

2021-04-15 15:35:07.079768+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP: Add transaction observer
2021-04-15 15:35:07.080293+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP: UpdatedTransactions
2021-04-15 15:35:07.084949+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Request to initiate queued payments
Already recorded transaction 1000000801477725
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:ProcessPurchaseIfNew(Product)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.JSONStore:OnPurchaseSucceeded(String, String, String)
System.Action:Invoke()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()
 
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 39)

2021-04-15 15:35:07.095638+0300 mygame[1699:852283] UnityIAP: Finishing transaction 1000000801477725
```

The last line of the above log, shows that ProcessPurchase callback method is called during app launch and transaction has tried to complete again.

Here is my sandbox code I used during testing :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PurchaseController : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{
    private IStoreController _storeController;
    private IExtensionProvider _extensionProvider;

    [SerializeField] private Button _purchaseButton;
    
    private string _miniCoinPack = "mini_coin_pack";

    private void Awake()
    {
        _purchaseButton.onClick.AddListener(BuyConsumable);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (_storeController == null)
        {
            InitializePurchasing();
        }
    }
    
    private void InitializePurchasing()
    {
        if (IsInitialized()) return;
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
        builder.AddProduct(_miniCoinPack, ProductType.Consumable);
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }
    
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        _storeController = controller;
        _extensionProvider = extensions;
        
        foreach (var product in _storeController.products.set)
        {
            if (product.hasReceipt)
            {
                _storeController.ConfirmPendingPurchase(product);
            }
            if (product.availableToPurchase)
            {
                Log(product.metadata.localizedTitle + ", is ready to purchase!");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        Log("OnInitializeFailed: " + error);
    }
    
    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
        return _storeController != null && _extensionProvider != null;
    }
    
    public void BuyConsumable()
    {
        BuyProductID(_miniCoinPack);
    }
    
    private void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            Product product = _storeController.products.WithID(productId);
            if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
            {
                Log(string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));
                _storeController.InitiatePurchase(product, "{\"userID\":\"313131696969\"}");
            }
            else
            {
                Log("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
        }
    }

    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args)
    {
        Log("purchase success for : " + args.purchasedProduct.definition.id);
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }

    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
    {
        Log(string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed, Product : {0}, Reason : {1}", product.definition.storeSpecificId, failureReason));
        var transactionHistoryExtensions = _extensionProvider.GetExtension<ITransactionHistoryExtensions>();
        Log("Store specific error code: " + transactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastStoreSpecificPurchaseErrorCode());
        if (transactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastPurchaseFailureDescription() != null)
        {
            Log("Purchase failure description message: " + transactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastPurchaseFailureDescription().message);
        }
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Concat("PurchaseController - ,", message));
    }
}
```

I have tried different ways to integrate UnityIAP into my sandbox Unity project like :

- using only unity package manager and installing (2.2.7 & 3.0.2 respectively)
- activating In-App Purchasing & Analytics services and installing UnityIAP package from there.

**Unity Version** : 2019.4.22f1, 2019.4.23f1

**Unity IAP Version** : 2.2.7, 3.0.2

**Test Device** : iPhone 6, iOS 12.5.1

**Test User** : Sandbox Tester (Country : United States, Interrupted Purchases : disabled, Apple Pay: Yes)

**App Store Connect App Status** : Prepare For Submission (Not submitted yet!)

**In App Purchase Items** : (Type:Consumable, Status:Ready To Submit)

It seems like this problem is fixed with UnityIAP-2.2.2 version as stated here : https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-iap-package-3-0-2-is-now-available.415517/page-2
but it still exist in 2.2.7 & 3.0.2 versions.

Is there anyone else who face the same or similar behaviour while implementing UnityIAP?

Comment: It seems like the problem is related to Apple side as seen in the following topics :
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678070?page=2
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678105?answerId=671160022#671160022

Answer (score 0):

I did confirm on 4 game that this is something on Apple server side.
It is not only for Unity IAP it is for everyone.
There is a lot of those issues https://developer.apple.com/forums/search/?q=sandbox&page=1&sortBy=newest